How do i fix or get rid of these jagged lines inside the donut?
I recently started using blender using Blender Guru's donut tutorial and found a problem that I cannot fix. I tried restarting my system preferences or restarting the donut from scratch but still can't seem to eliminate the jagged lines inside the donut. (This problem started when I deleted the bottom half of its duplicate for icing) 

This looks like the kind of thing that happens when you have a bunch of tight odd geometry, and the smooth shading tries to draw a bunch of sharp angles that are invisible to you. Long story short, you missed a step. I can try to watch the tutorial and figure out what you did wrong. I recommend you share your file with blend-exchange.com in the meantime.
